# Unit testing method that uses callback and SynchronousQueue to track results

Tags: java, unit-testing, callback, mockito

I'm using Mockito to test a method that internally makes a networking call and returns a value based on the result of the networking call. This method uses a SynchronousQueue to wait for the result, and the result is set by the callback for the networking call:

```
HelperClass helperClassObject = new HelperClassObject();

...

public SomeResultCode methodWithNetworkCall() {
    SynchronousQueue<SomeResultCode> resultQueue = new SynchronousQueue<>();

    // some condition checking code

    helperClassObject.makeNetworkCall(new GenericCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {
            resultQueue.offer(SomeResultCode.SUCCESS);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(VolleyError error) {
            resultQueue.offer(SomeResultCode.FAILURE);
        }
    });

    SomeResultCode resultCode = null;
    try {
        resultCode = resultQueue.poll(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
    return resultCode == null ? SomeResultCode.FAILURE : resultCode;
}
```

In one of my unit test methods I'm trying to verify that SUCCESS is returned upon successful network call. I've tried using ArgumentCaptor and doAnswer to trigger the callback's onSuccess. However, the method is returning FAILURE. I put a breakpoint in the onSuccess, and it looks like when I use the ArgumentCaptor way the onSuccess is triggered AFTER the poll has timed out. When I use the doAnswer way, I see onSuccess called during the setup (doAnswer.when) but not after I actually call the method. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Stepping through the code again, it looks like answer is called from within the method I'm testing (i.e. when I call testObject.methodWithNetworkCall during my test), NOT during setup. So it is doing exactly what it is supposed to do: responding with onSuccess. But it is responding with onSuccess BEFORE poll is called. So it seems the problem is not that answer and mocking in general is not working/set up wrong, it is an issue with testing with SynchronousQueue.

Here is my test code:

```
public class TestClassUnitTest {
    TestClass sut;
    HelperClass helperClassObject = mock(HelperClass.class);

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        sut = new TestClass();
        injectField(sut, "helperClassFieldName", helperClassObject);
    }

    public void injectField(Object testObject, String fieldName, T mockToInject) {
        // some code using reflection to inject the mock object into the test object
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodWithNetworkCallWithCaptor() {
        ArgumentCaptor<GenericCallback> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(GenericCallback.class);
        SomeResultCode result = sut.methodWithNetworkcall();
        verify(helperClassObject, times(1)).makeNetworkCall(captor.capture());
        captor.getValue().onSuccess(new JSONObject());
        Assert.assertEquals(SomeResultCode.SUCCESS, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodWithNetworkCallWithDoAnswer() {
        doAnswer(new Answer(){
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                ((GenericCallback)invocation.getArguments()[0]).onSuccess(new JSONObject());
                return null;
            }
        }).when(helperClassObject).makeNetworkCall(any(GenericCallback.class));
        SomeResultCode result = sut.methodWithNetworkcall();
        Assert.assertEquals(SomeResultCode.SUCCESS, result);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case using `doAnswer` IS the correct approach. The issue is with the way `SynchronousQueue` worked: it expects multi-threaded usage of this queue:

> A blocking queue in which each insert operation must wait for a corresponding remove operation **by another thread**, and vice versa.

But in this testing case the test runs on a single thread.

Solution: mock the `SynchronousQueue`, and use `doAnswer` to get `offer()` and `poll()` to push/pop result onto a LinkedList. In the process, I also moved the `SynchrnousQueue` local variable `resultQueue` out of `methodWithNetworkCall()` and made it an instance member. Updated test code below:

```
public class TestClassUnitTest {
    TestClass sut;
    private LinkedList testQueue = new LinkedList();
    private SynchronousQueue<SomeResultCode> resultQueueMock = mock(SynchronousQueue.class);
    private HelperClass helperClassMock = mock(HelperClass.class);

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        sut = new TestClass();
        injectField(sut, "resultQueue", resultQueueMock);
        injectField(sut, "helperClassFieldName", helperClassMock);
    }

    public void injectField(Object testObject, String fieldName, T mockToInject) {
        // some code using reflection to inject the mock object into the test object
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodWithNetworkCallWithDoAnswer() {
        doAnswer(new Answer(){
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                ((GenericCallback)invocation.getArguments()[0]).onSuccess(new JSONObject());
                return null;
            }
        }).when(helperClassMock).makeNetworkCall(any(GenericCallback.class));
        mockQueue();
        SomeResultCode result = sut.methodWithNetworkCall();
        Assert.assertEquals(SomeResultCode.SUCCESS, result);
    }

    private void mockQueue() {
        doAnswer(new Answer() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                testQueue.push(((SchedulableJob.Result)invocation.getArguments()[0]));
                return true;
            }
        }).when(resultQueueMock).offer(any());

        try {
            doAnswer(new Answer() {
                @Override
                    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                    if (testQueue.size() > 0) {
                        return testQueue.pop();
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }).when(resultQueueMock).poll(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not replacing your HelperClassObject in your system-under-test, or at least you haven't shown us where you have. The mock returned by `Mockito.mock` (or `@Mock` or `spy` or `@Spy`) doesn't apply to every instance of the class you pass in; it just creates a single instance. You have to make sure to set the instance (HelperClassObject here) in your system-under-test, possibly by passing it in as a constructor parameter, setting the instance as a field, or setting it using a setter method. If you leave it as `new HelperClassObject()` as you've shown us, there's no way Mockito will be able to help you.

Your reference to "onSuccess called during the setup (doAnswer.when)" worries me a little bit, because if you've created a mock using `Mockito.mock`, there should be no reason Mockito would actually call your Answer during setup. This leads me to believe that your HelperClassObject or `makeNetworkcall` method can't be mocked, possibly from having limited visibility, or because they're marked `static` or `final`. Mockito effectively works by writing a custom subclass of the class you're mocking, so make sure the classes and methods you're mocking are `public` and non-`final` to ensure they're overridable. (It is possible to mock `protected` or package-private methods, but certain versions of Mockito have complications with certain code structures. Let's rule that out first.)

After you make sure that the class is mockable and that it's using the mocked HelperClassObject instance you pass in, you'll be able to move forward. You'll want to pursue the `doAnswer` structure: The ArgumentCaptor version won't work, because if your `methodWithNetworkcall` blocks and waits for a result, then you'll get a `FAILURE` return value before you ever get a chance to `verify` and call your callback. (That explains the timeout.) In other cases where your method-under-test can return first, the ArgumentCaptor solution will be more practical for you.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your response. It seems I misspoke about when the answer was triggered. I just stepped through the code again and see that answer is called form within the method I'm testing (i.e. when I call testObject.methodWithNetworkCall during my test). It is doing exactly what it is supposed to do: responding with onSuccess. It seems the problem is not that answer and mocking in general is not working/set up wrong, it is that using synchronousqueue makes this method not testable since it is all happening on one thread :-/

Comment: @hcabrams I'm afraid I don't have much of a solution, other than `doAnswer` (which should work—can you make a SSCCE?), or laboriously introducing multithreading to your test. If you can refactor away SynchronousQueue to a (Listenable)Future instead, you can leave it up to the consumer about whether to block or not, and might make your code easier to test as well.

Comment: for context, methodWithNetworkCall is really an override of a library method that requires the return of a `SomeResultCode`, so I think I'm stuck with having to block until the network call returns. However, I managed to figure out a way to test, will post answer below. Thanks for your thorough responses: I'm relatively new to testing with Mockito so your explanations on how things work/are supposed to be set up are very helpful!